# Add a value from a json file in the tooltip with NVD3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm quite new with the NVD3 library.
I have a linechart with a simple tooltip. I activated the footer and I would like to load in the footer a different value for every couple (x,y).

What is the best solution in NVD3?

I was trying to insert in the json file another attribute with the z value.

Json:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Marketable",
    "color": "#A09FA2",
    "area" : "false",
    "values": [
      {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 5220593,
        "z": 5220593
      },
      {
        "x": 2,
        "y": 5220593,
        "z": 5220593
      },
...
```

And in the library I would like to use the z value, is it possible ?

```
Below here the code:

       var contentGenerator = function(d) {
            if (content != null) {
                return content;
            }

            if (d == null) {
                return '';
            }

            var table = d3.select(document.createElement("table"));
            var theadEnter = table.selectAll("thead")
                .data([d])
                .enter().append("thead");
            theadEnter.append("tr")
                .append("td")
                .attr("colspan",3)
                .append("strong")
                .classed("x-value",true)
                .html(headerFormatter("Round "+d.value+", ratio "+{***here I would like to take the z value***}.value+"%"));
```

Comment: If you're going to post that large a code dump, you might as well create a stack snippet.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/silviosangineto/2q7tv7L5/14/

Comment: You can make a jsfiddle-esque insertion in your post. When editing, search for the stack snippet (it's a page with the `<>` brackets) button. (jsfiddle links can die; the stack snippet will stay with the post 5ever)

Comment: I edited my original post. Now, I hope that it will be more clear.